# How do I access value of an object?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple constant as below:

```
const student=[{"Name":"Sam"}]
```

I want to access the name property of it
I tried the below 2 codes but am getting the values as undefined.

```
const student=[{"Name":"Sam"}]
const temp=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(student))
console.log(temp['Name'])//returns undefined
console.log(temp.Name)//also return undefined
```

Is there any other way I do it?

Comment: const student=["Name":"Sam"]
this part is wrong here should be curly brackets

Comment: isn't your constant supposed to be `student = {"Name":"Sam"}` ?

Comment: There was a typo..I 've corrected it now

Comment: You have an object? or an  array of objects?

Comment: array of objects with only 1 element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array of object You need to use correct index of array and then use property to access of your object:

```
const student=[{"Name":"Sam"}]
const temp=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(student))
console.log(temp[0]['Name'])//returns Sam
console.log(temp[0].Name)//also return Sam
```

Comment: @riya Do you need to create loop and show all names?

Comment: Then dont use array./

Comment: Yes if you have one object in your array there is no need to use array. But note that we can convert array to object but in your case simplest way is use one object or if you insist on array use index is best case for you

Answer (score 3):

Build a proper Object, not array

```
const student={"Name":"Sam"} // CURLY BRACES NOT BRACKETS,
const temp=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(student))
console.log(temp['Name'])//returns Sam
console.log(temp.Name)//also return Sam
```

After question was edited: you are creating array of objects, thus you must point to which object you are referring to (array index) and then its property

```
const student=[{"Name":"Sam"}] ;
const temp=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(student))
console.log(temp[0]['Name'])//returns Sam - of the first element
console.log(temp[0].Name)//also return Sam - of the first element
```

If you don't want to use array index, use first variant.

Comment: there was atypo and it's been corrected...but then I had to use temp[0].Name...Can't I directly use without index?

Comment: @riya Are you sure you always had a one object in your array?

Comment: @riya either creat array and use temp[0].Name or do as I wrote in the first version of answer  without array.

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces instead of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax will be `student[0].Name`

`student` is an array of objects. You have to select the node at index 0 and access the key `Name` of the same.

```js
const student=[{"Name":"Sam"}]
console.log(student[0].Name)//returns Sam
```

**What went worng in your code?**

You tried to access name with `temp['Name']` and `temp.Name` for this to work `temp` hould be an object like `{"Name":"Sam"}` instead its an Array like `[{"Name":"Sam"}]`. So you have to go for either `temp[0]['Name']` or `temp[0].Name`